# Header special char conversion?

Tags: php, utf-8, header, meta-tags

I have some problems with char conversion on my php's page header.

I have to develop a snippet of code that, means WS (xml-rpc protocol), can interface with another snippet of code wrote in python.

This is python snippet's output:

```
Output={'metaTagKeyWords': '', 'metaTagTitle': '10% DISCOUNT FOR 3 NIGHTS','metaTagDescription': 'Questa \xc3\xa8 una prova: devo vedere che succede.\r\n\r\nProva prova.\r\n\r\nDaje.\r\n\r\nENGLISH VERSION !!!!\r\n'}
```

So I have to convert some char: first of all *\xc3\xa8* that is the unicode conversion of "è" and, in a second time, the *"\r\n\"* chars.

I know how to procede with *"\r\n\"* chars, but I don't know how to convert the unicode char.

I have had alredy tried to do something like this:

```
htmlentities($data[$META_TITLE_KEY], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

But it dind't work.

Moreover, I had alredy tried to convert in pyhon the string in UTF-8 (so that entity would be *u'\xc3'* or something like that, but the results are pretty the same.)

An additional info: that conversion have to be used on php file header, into "meta tag description" tag.

EDIT1:

It's seems to be that, what we belive as an UTF-8, is instead a LATIN-1. So, if i change in the header that part:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

in

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

it works.

But I have to have a utf-8 charset; so I suppose that have to do something in python applicative logic (because when I go from editor to DB i encode something while when I return from DB to editor I decode something).
Stay tune for more info

EDIT2:

Maybe some function that i use to save my data onto Postrges DMB, convert data in latin-1 and then in utf-8. So, if I add this instruction:

```
d_meta[element] = codeDbToEditor(d_meta[element]).replace('\r\n', ' ').decode('latin-1')
```

everything seems to works.

Have I had the right "insipration"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="Hello Loréane";
echo utf8_encode($str);
```

Hope It Helps

Comment: I have to do the opposite thing, so decode from utf-8, so maybe: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php ?

Comment: Muthu, When posting code on SO, please make sure that you indent each line with four spaces so that it is wrapped in a PRE tag and properly highlighted for easier reading.

Comment: This is the output of utf8_decode: ? (seems to dind't convert)